# Join datatables using column names stored in variables

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have 2 data.tables:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:5, value1 = 11:15, value2 = 21:25, value3 = 36:40)
dt2 <- data.table(name = c("value1", "value1", "value1", "value1", 
                            "value2", "value2", "value2", "value3", "value3"), 
              valueMin = c(10, 13, 14, 18, 21, 24, 25, 36, 38), 
              valueMax = c(13, 14, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 38, 42), 
              label = c(101:104, 201:203, 301:302))
> dt1
   id value1 value2 value3
1:  1     11     21     36
2:  2     12     22     37
3:  3     13     23     38
4:  4     14     24     39
5:  5     15     25     40
> dt2
     name valueMin valueMax label
1: value1       10       13   101
2: value1       13       14   102
3: value1       14       18   103
4: value1       18       20   104
5: value2       21       24   201
6: value2       24       25   202
7: value2       25       27   203
8: value3       36       38   301
9: value3       38       42   302
```

The result I expect is the following: joining label from `dt2` to `dt1` by the fact that `value1` in `dt1` is between valueMin and valueMax in `dt2` and `dt2$name` matches to `value1`).
Here is a solution I have (gives correct result):

```
varName <- "value1"
dt2_temp <- dt2[name == varName,]
dt1[dt2_temp, on = .(value1 > valueMin, value1 <= valueMax), nomatch = 0] %>%
select(id, label)
   id label
   1:  1   101
   2:  2   101
   3:  3   101
   4:  4   102
   5:  5   103
```

I would like to do the same (get `label` columns) for all the rest columns (`value2`, `value3`) in `dt1` (using loop), therefore need to replace reference to column name `value1` in join to it's name stored in `varName`, something like:

```
dt1[dt2_temp, on = .(varName > valueMin, varName <= valueMax), nomatch = 0]
```

Unfortunately, I did not succeed using: simply `varName`, `eval(varName)`, `as.name(varName)`. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Error message is similar to:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, dt2_temp, on = .(varName > valueMin, varName <= valueMax),  : 
>   Column(s) [varName,varName] not found in x
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not do it all in one go without a loop?

A possible solution:

```
melt(dt1, id = 1)[dt2, on = .(variable = name, value > valueMin, value <= valueMax), lbl := i.label
                  ][, dcast(.SD, id ~ variable, value.var = c("value","lbl"))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id value_value1 value_value2 value_value3 lbl_value1 lbl_value2 lbl_value3
> 1:  1           11           21           36        101         NA         NA
> 2:  2           12           22           37        101        201        301
> 3:  3           13           23           38        101        201        301
> 4:  4           14           24           39        102        201        302
> 5:  5           15           25           40        103        202        302
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Posting another method that programmatically constructs the `on` string (see the `on` argument in `?data.table`)

```
dt1[dt2_temp, 
    on=c(paste0(varName, ">valueMin"), paste0(varName, "<=valueMax")),
    nomatch=0L]
```

Note that there should not be any space around the variable names.

Answer (score 2):

```
melt(dt1,1)[dt2, on = .(value> valueMin, value <= valueMax,variable=name), nomatch = 0]

   id variable value value.1 label
 1:  1   value1    10      13   101
 2:  2   value1    10      13   101
 3:  3   value1    10      13   101
 4:  4   value1    13      14   102
 5:  5   value1    14      18   103
 6:  2   value2    21      24   201
 7:  3   value2    21      24   201
 8:  4   value2    21      24   201
 9:  5   value2    24      25   202
10:  2   value3    36      38   301
11:  3   value3    36      38   301
12:  4   value3    38      42   302
13:  5   value3    38      42   302
```

Comment: you aren't joining correctly, you need to take valuename into account as well ....

Comment: @Jaap sure sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the approach could be

```
library(data.table)

dcast(dt2[melt(dt1, id.vars = 1),    #left join of long form of dt1 and original dt2
          .( id, variable, label),   #only keep concerned columns from merged table
          on = .(name = variable,  valueMax >= value, valueMin < value)],  #join conditions
      id ~ variable, 
      value.var = "label")           #long to wide format using dcast to get the final result
```

which gives

```
   id value1 value2 value3
1:  1    101     NA     NA
2:  2    101    201    301
3:  3    101    201    301
4:  4    102    201    302
5:  5    103    202    302
```

Comment: you need `valueMax >= value` instead of `valueMax > value`

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you @Jaap for highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

With a mix of `tidyverse` and `fuzzyjoin` :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

dt2 %>% fuzzy_inner_join(
  gather(dt1,name, value,-1),
  by=c("name",valueMin="value",valueMax="value"),
  list(function(x,y) x == y,
       function(x,y) x < y,
       function(x,y) x >= y)) %>%
  select(id,name.x,label) %>%
  distinct %>%
  spread(name.x,label)

#    id value1 value2 value3
# 1:  1    101     NA     NA
# 2:  2    101    201    301
# 3:  3    101    201    301
# 4:  4    102    201    302
# 5:  5    103    202    302
```