# Join datatables using more than one column name stored in one variable

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to perform an update join of two data tables with the fields (more than one) I need to use to join stored in a variable. Below is an example:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 5:1, lett = letters[1:5])
DT2 <- data.table(col1 = c(1:3, 2:5, 1), col2 = c(5:3, 4:1, 5))

joinFields <- c('col1', 'col2')
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
DT1[DT2,
    on=c(paste0(joinFields, '=', joinFields)),
    nomatch=0L]
```

This way is based on a solution suggested in [Join datatables using column names stored in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186683/join-datatables-using-column-names-stored-in-variables).

```
dt1[dt2_temp, 
    on=c(paste0(varName, ">valueMin"), paste0(varName, "<=valueMax")),
    nomatch=0L]
```

It does not work. Obviously, my case is a bit different, because in the example I used, there are 2 pastes. Is there a solution that continues to allow me using `on = c()`?

Edit: I am aware I can do it with `merge`()`

Comment: You mention "update join" but don't use `:=`. Could you show and explain the desired output? Btw, you might need `"=="` not `"="` there, I guess, eg `DT1[DT2, on=sprintf("%s==%s", joinFields, joinFields)]`

Comment: the keys used to join appears to be the same in both tables so why not `DT1[DT2, on=joinFields, nomatch=0L]` ?

Comment: @Frank, thanks for your suggestion. It is indeed not an update join. I was a bit lazy and copied from the other thread. I should have added `let := i.lett`

Comment: @chinsoon12, thanks that is a very short solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to put two ==, as following:

```
DT1[DT2,
    on=c(paste0(joinFields, '==', joinFields)),
    nomatch=0L]
# col1 col2 lett
# 1:    1    5    a
# 2:    2    4    b
# 3:    3    3    c
# 4:    2    4    b
# 5:    3    3    c
# 6:    4    2    d
# 7:    5    1    e
# 8:    1    5    a
```

Even you do not need to use `c()` :

```
 DT1[DT2,
        on=paste0(joinFields, '==', joinFields),
        nomatch=0L]
    # col1 col2 lett
    # 1:    1    5    a
    # 2:    2    4    b
    # 3:    3    3    c
    # 4:    2    4    b
    # 5:    3    3    c
    # 6:    4    2    d
    # 7:    5    1    e
    # 8:    1    5    a
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Carles Sans Fuentes. I must say I have some things to look into, because I don't understand why it works with the `==` operator. I generally join like this `DT1[DT2, on = .(col1 = col1, col2 = col2), nomatch=0L]`

Comment: @koteletje It's just the documented behavior with strings in `on=` (from `?data.table`)

Comment: Happy to help @koteletje. We all need to be checking staff. Regarding your question of why it is two equals: besides being stated like that on the `data.table` documentation,  the standard way to check if an object/something is exactly equal than another object/something is using logical operators, and it is stablished as two equals . Check this link for further understanding of it: statmethods.net/management/operators.html